# ffmpeg conversion is very slow - How to optimize it?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am cropping and splitting a video of size 13476*1500 into 4 parts, below is the filters. The conversion is very very slow! Is there a faster way to convert the videos? please help!

And also i want to know if there is an alternative way to do the same job or with handbrake.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=2691:1200:0:0[out1];[0:v]crop=4036:1200:2691:0[out2];[0:v]crop=2691:1200:6727:0[out3];[0:v]crop=4036:1200:9418:0[out4]" -map [out1] -map 0:a out1.mp4 -map [out2] -map 0:a out2.mp4 -map [out3] -map 0:a out3.mp4 -map [out4] -map 0:a out4.mp4
```

Comment: What is the size of input.mp4 ?

Comment: I note that you have left the output video stream to default, you could experiment with the faster presets for libx264 +/- different crf settings...

Comment: @SorenA input size is 90mb, 8 sec video

Comment: @andrew.46 i have tried the crf 24 and also tried Ultrafast preset, but i didn't see any difference.

Comment: @user3416431 Hmmm... almost out of ideas here but perhaps some experimentation with the `threads n` option? My suspicion is that omitting this value completely or specifying `threads 0` might be the best option anyway but it might be worth a go...

Comment: @andrew.46 thanks, i tried thread with 0 to 4 and did not find any difference. Is there any other alternative? with handbrake?

Comment: It's discouraged to crosspost [the same question](https://superuser.com/questions/1447352/ffmpeg-conversion-is-very-slow-how-to-optimize-it) on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @user3416431 Handbrake uses FFmpeg :)